# Jquery Cookies not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using jquery pluging jquery.cookies.js for cookies.

here is part of my code

```
    var firstName = 'mayank',
    email = 'mayank.bhadauria@gmail.com';

    $.cookie('candidateName', firstName, {expires: 2, path:'/', domain: 'localhost'});
    $.cookie('candidateEmail', email, {expires: 2, path:'/', domain: 'localhost'});

    var nameFromCookies = $.cookie('candidateName');
    var emailFromCookies = $.cookie('candidateEmail');

    console.log(nameFromCookies+' '+emailFromCookies);
```

I am not getting anything in console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a high probability that the path and domain doesn't match, try

```
$.cookie('candidateName', firstName, { expires: 2 });
$.cookie('candidateEmail', email, { expires: 2 });
```

and see if that works

Comment: YES ... Its working, I thought path is to store cookies location in system and doesn't depends on domain .

Comment: The path and domain is where the cookie will be accessible, so setting the `/` as path, and localhost as domain, means the cookie is ***only*** available on the root of localhost, and nowhere else. By just removing those settings, the cookie is available for 2 days across your site.

Comment: when i am not giving path and domain than what will be the default values it will take?

Comment: it has taken root folder of my project and domain localhost as default.